# git log format prints empty dates

Tags: git

I have a git repository in which all of the commits are performed on a schedule using a Python script and the [dulwich](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dulwich) library.

I'm trying to print the list of commits with their commit dates, using `git log` with a custom format, but I can't find a format string that works.

Here's what I get for a single commit when I run `git log --format=raw`:

```
commit d955a72160fdacfc7c22eccdccaf8b343c882ebb
tree d6b8baffb86d16b90552250da7bfe39828d16982
parent 03bccd572a8ed7e04c96bf27a010d7ef39165e1c
author auto.py 1381493109 +0000
committer auto.py 1381493109 +0000

    commit message
```

Compare that to a repo where all the commits have been created by the actual git tool, also with `--format=raw`:

```
commit 72dbd4358c8685cfd604b4146c7728c82999a97e
tree cfc5254c5f96b50ec6b5abf1b573e97989a52b19
parent 2f2a87f7f1e87afe1b93d659e4cd435532352ada
author me <me@example.com> 1381503599 -0300
committer me <me@example.com> 1381503599 -0300

    commit message
```

Using the `git log --format` documentation, I constructed a format string that should show the author & commit dates in every format, surrounded on both sides by the commit hash. I then ran it on the dulwich-managed repo:

```
$ git log --format="format:%h %an %ad %aD %ar %at %ai %cn %cd %cD %ar %at %ai %h"
d955a72             d955a72
```

And for the git-managed repo:

```
$ git log --format="format:%h %an %ad %aD %ar %at %ai %cn %cd %cD %ar %at %ai %h"
72dbd43 me Fri Oct 11 11:59:59 2013 -0300 Fri, 11 Oct 2013 11:59:59 -0300 5 days ago 1381503599 2013-10-11 11:59:59 -0300 mRB0 Fri Oct 11 11:59:59 2013 -0300 Fri, 11 Oct 2013 11:59:59 -0300 5 days ago 1381503599 2013-10-11 11:59:59 -0300 72dbd43
```

Every date is an empty string. I guess that dulwich stored the commit dates differently, but I can't find any way to access them in the format string.

Is there any custom format I can use with `git log` to access the timestamps in the dulwich commits?

I am using git version 1.8.3.4 (Apple Git-47).

Comment: @AntoinePelisse Oops! I included the wrong commit. Just did another `git log --format=raw` and updated my question — the two are a lot more similar now.

Comment: Yes and I believe that proves the point on my answer. You can have a look at this: https://github.com/gitster/git/blob/master/ident.c#L201

Comment: You could also try running `git fsck` in the repository. I believe it will display errors in *unparsable commits*.

Comment: @AntoinePelisse You got it: `error in commit d955a72160fdacfc7c22eccdccaf8b343c882ebb: invalid author/committer line - missing email`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the commit created by dulwich is invalid, because the author and committer email address is always mandatory in Git (the parser is looking for enclosing `<>`). Failure in parsing the *author/committer ident* results in not parsing the timestamp.

Comment: Yeah, Dulwich should probably verify that the author/committer value specified is valid and raise an exception if it isn't, rather than blindly writing it to disk.

Answer (score 0):

Antoine Pelisse's answer is correct: My commits have no email address in their author/committer records, so they aren't valid and git can't parse them for formatting.

I was able to repair my repositories by executing the following filter in the working directory. Note that this will update ALL commit authors unconditionally:

```
git filter-branch --env-filter "
GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL='foo@bar.com'
GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL='foo@bar.com'
GIT_AUTHOR_NAME='auto.py'
GIT_COMMITTER_NAME='auto.py'
"
```

Luckily, git maintains the author and commit dates during the above filter. (Verified on git version 1.7.2.5 and git version 1.8.3.4 (Apple Git-47))

To avoid the problem in future commits, I made the following change when committing through dulwich:

```
# old: do not use
# repo.do_commit("message", committer="auto.py")

# fixed
repo.do_commit("message", committer="auto.py <foo@bar.com>")
```

After the above, my `git log` format strings work properly.

Comment: I don't understand why dulwich made it different from cgit: Author name and author email are two different things then concatenated by git, yet here you have to format yourself.